# Python function to return a list or work as a generator?

Tags: python, generator

I was experimenting with creating a function that returns an object or works as a generator.

This is a bad idea because, as a best practice, you want functions to reliably return the same types of values, but in the interest of science...

I'm using Python 2, and so `range` returns a list, and `xrange` is an iterable (that interestingly also provides a `__len__`).

```
def xr(start, stop=None, step=1, gen=True):
    if stop is None:
        start, stop = 0, start
    if gen == True:
        for i in xrange(start, stop, step):
            yield i
    else:
        return range(start, stop, step)
```

I get this error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 8
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
```

### Questions:

Why (beyond the obvious "you can't have both yield and return in a function," assuming that's right) does it do this? Looking at my code, it is not readily apparent why it would be bad to do this.

How would I attempt to get around this? I know I can return xrange instead of yielding each item from xrange, and so I could return a generator created in another function, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)?

```
>>> def xr(start, stop=None, step=1, gen=True):
...     if stop is None:
...         start, stop = 0, start
...     if gen == True:
...         return (i for i in xrange(start, stop, step)) # <----
...     else:
...         return range(start, stop, step)
...
>>> xr(2, gen=False)
[0, 1]
>>> xr(2, gen=True)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000002C1C828>
>>> list(xr(2, gen=True))
[0, 1]
```

BTW, I would rather define a generator function only. Then use `list(xr(..))` if I need a list.

**UPDATE** Alternatively you can use `iter(xrange(start, stop, step))` instead of the generator expression as @DSM commented. See [Built-in functions -- `iter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter).

Comment: `(i for i in xrange(start, stop, step))` can be written `iter(xrange(start, stop, step))`.

Comment: @DSM, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer according to you.

Comment: But the function itself is not a generator - it __returns__ a generator.

Comment: @volcano: The post didn't ask for it to *be* a generator but to "work as a generator" (which on a Pythonic duck-typing view is all that matters anyway).

Comment: @volcano: Yes, it does, because when you call it when `gen=True` what you get is a generator.

Comment: Yes, that does do what I was asking, and I asked for a better way than the possibilities I suggested, and there they are, although I think ``iter`` is much nicer than ``i for i in ``, +! from asker.

Comment: Usually you don't need that kind of interface, because you may always convert generator expression to list with a _list_ function

Answer (score 8):

falsetru has given you a way to have a function that returns a generator or a list.  I'm answering your other question about why you can't have a return and a yield in the same function.

When you call a generator function, it doesn't actually do anything immediately (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)).  It doesn't execute the function body, but waits until you start iterating over it (or call `next` on it).  Therefore, Python has to know if the function is a generator function or not at the beginning, when you call it, to know whether to run the function body or not.

It doesn't make sense to then have it return some value, because if it's a generator function what it returns is the generator (i.e., the thing you iterate over).  If you could have a return inside a generator function, it wouldn't be reached when you called the function, so the function would have to "spontaneously" return a value at some later point (when the `return` statement was reached as the generator was consumed), which would either be the same as yielding a value at that time, or would be something bizarre and confusing.

I agree with falsetru that it's probably not a great idea to have a function that sometimes returns a generator and sometimes a list.  Just call `list` on the generator if you want a list.

Comment: I agree, not a best practice. The above was the result of an experiment that I half expected to fail before starting. But that's learning, and now I'll always expect it to fail. Do you have a more canonical source to refer me to?

Comment: @AaronHall: Basic descriptions of generators are in [PEP 255](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) and [PEP 342](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have both because interpreter - when it encounters keyword *yield* - treats the function as a generator function. And obviously you cannot have a return statement in a generator function.
Additional point - you don't use generator functions directly, you use them to create (I am tempted to say instantiate) generators.
Simple example

```
def infinite():
    cnt = 1
    while True:
        yield cnt
        cnt += 1

infinite_gen = infinite()
```

**infinite** is generator function and **infinite_gen** is generator